# NotifyDataSetChanged is not working in my code

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not working in android i am retrieving the values in for loop but the values are not displaying on the screen.
My java file:

```
private static final String TAG_NAME="Notification";
String[] resultsAsString = {""};
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultsAsString);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseObjectParseQuery=new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("PushNotifications");
    parseObjectParseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null){
                resultsAsString = new String[objects.size()];
                Log.d(TAG_NAME,"Objects size in MyService is:"+objects.size());

                if(objects.size()>0){
                    Log.d(TAG_NAME,"Object size is "+objects.size());
                    for(int index = 0; index < objects.size(); index++){
                        resultsAsString[index] = objects.get(index).getString("Message");
                        Log.d(TAG_NAME,"result value is:"+resultsAsString[index]);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else {
                    Log.d(TAG_NAME,"Object size is "+objects.size());
                }
            }
        }
    });
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notificatio_listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my logcat display:
Objects size in MyService is:3
Object size is 3
First Nottification
second message
Third message

Comment: are you sure objects.size() is >0 ?

Comment: Ya i am sure objects size is 3 and i can view in for loop

Comment: and...usually, call adapterNotifyDataSetChanged() after you set the adapter to listView......

Comment: Have you tried setting the adapter after you initialize it? I mean, putting these 2 last lines of code after adapter = new .....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs that's not necessary to call that method after you set an Adapter, only after the underlying data is changed

Comment: i think you are losing reference of original array (the one passed to the adapter) so calling notify... will not work as expected because the original array (passed to adapter) still empty

Comment: what I meant was, that it makes no sense to call notifyAdapterSetChanged without setting adapter to listview....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs the Adapter is set. Parse is non-blocking so that code happens after a network request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You created a brand new array and it is not attached to the adapter.

```
resultsAsString = new String[objects.size()];
```

The notify does work, but you no longer have the reference to that dataset in the adapter in order to update it. The adapter is still holding onto the initial, empty String array

I'd recommend you use an Arraylist and simply `adapter.add` to fill in data. With that, there's no need to notify

And also use `adapter.clear` when the Parse result is complete unless you want duplicate data

---

Alternatively, just make a new Adapter and set it on the ListView again

Comment: exactly, the notifyDataSetChanged() still work on the originally passed array which remained empty, because data was added to a new array.

Comment: Hi cricket_007, thanks for the answer, what should i use now Arraylist or adapter?

Comment: Those are two different things. An ArrayList is stored *inside* the adapter. Just like your `String[]`... so replace that with `ArrayList<String>`